# Weird pill shaped icon in the dock

Tags: macos, dock

I have noticed a pill shaped object in my dock. When moving the doc it stays in the same place.

Restarting didn't resolve the issue.

Does anyone have an idea what this object might be and how I can get rid of it?

[image: Pill shaped object in Doc]

Comment: is there any download in progress ?

Comment: No, not that I know of.

Comment: check the downloads folder for any .download files.

Comment: `$ cd ~/Downloads` 
`$ ls *.download`
`$ zsh: no matches found: *.download` No luck either.

Comment: A sharing program like dropbox stuck updating / uploading?

Comment: Are you emptying the trash or have you recently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw this under the Downloads folder and later it moved under trash.

- In Safari, downloads list, hit "clear".
- In trash, select all `.download` files ( kind: "Safari Downloads") and right click > "delete immediately".
- In Terminal, run

  ```
  killall Dock
  ```